# Digitalocean remote psql database with local PDO (RedBean php) script

Tags: php, pdo, psql, redbean

I've configured my psql DB on Digitalocean server to accept remote connections. Local script

```
psql -h addres-to-droplet -U Digitalocean -d Digitalocean_production
```

works like a charm (I have prompt to pass my password). When I use php script with Redbean I have PDO error like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'Could not
>   connect to database (Digitalocean_production).' in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php:830 Stack trace: #0
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php(657): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->connect()
>    #1 /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php(854): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #2
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php(3306):
>   RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #3
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php(10060):
>   RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->get('SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #4
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php(10751): RedBeanPHP\Facade::query('get',
>   'SELECT * FROM u...', Array) #5 /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php(10):
>   RedBeanPHP\Facade::getAll('SELECT * FROM u...') #6 {main} thrown in
>   /usr/share/nginx/html/rb.php on line 830

My R::setup looks like this

```
R::setup( 'pgsql:host=address-to-droplet;dbname=Digitalocean_production', 'Digitalocean', 'Digitalocean');
R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM users'); --that sql works with psql
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create PDO instance and then pass it to redbean setup function

```
$db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost;user=myuser;password=mypass');
R::setup($db);
```